# Patchwork does not collect guides

Tags: r, ggplot2, patchwork

Patchwork does not collect guides with code in [documentation](https://patchwork.data-imaginist.com/articles/guides/layout.html)... the reprex code is following:

Does anyone know what is causing the issue here, please?

```r
library(ggplot2)
#> Warning: package 'ggplot2' was built under R version 4.0.5
library(patchwork)
p1a <- ggplot(mtcars) + 
  geom_point(aes(mpg, disp, colour = mpg, size = wt)) + 
  ggtitle('Plot 1a')

p2 <- ggplot(mtcars) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(gear, disp, group = gear)) + 
  ggtitle('Plot 2')

p3 <- ggplot(mtcars) + 
  geom_point(aes(hp, wt, colour = mpg)) + 
  ggtitle('Plot 3')
p1a | (p2 / p3) + plot_layout(guides = 'collect')
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-11-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

[Session info](https://gist.github.com/liutiming/f3c99b00a1b715c8800f93d43fed2276) - patchwork is updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(p1a | (p2 / p3)) + plot_layout(guides = 'collect')
```

[image]

Without the parentheses, the plot_layout() will only relate to the immediately preceding term, `(p2 / p3)`. From the documentation for `plot_layout()`:

> If you are nesting grids, the layout is scoped to the current nesting
> level.

I think in this case "the current nesting level" will be the most recent term.